# вместе со span скрываются все элементы

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

надо скрыть спан с ссылкой для скринридера под иконкой соц.сетей, чтоб осталась только иконка, а ссылка с описанием соц.сети была за заплаткой, но когда скрываю спан, скрывается весь элемент, и иконку не видно, хотя обращаюсь к спану с заплаткой

```css
.footer {
  background-color: #f4f7f6;
  margin-left: 240px;
  width: 1170px;
  margin-bottom: 75px;
}

.socials {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 400px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.socials-item {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.socials-item:first-child {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.socials-link-twitter {
  background-image: url("https://html-2-diploma/sources/images/social/004-twitter.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.socials-link-printerest {
  background-image: url("https://html-2-diploma/sources/images/social/001-pinterest.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.socials-link-instagram {
  background-image: url("https://html-2-diploma/sources/images/social/005-instagram.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.socials-link-tumblr {
  background-image: url("https://html-2-diploma/sources/images/social/003-tumblr.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.socials-link-facebook {
  background-image: url("https://sources/images/social/002-facebook-logo.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 20px;
}

.socials-link-text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
  <ul class="socials">
    <li class="socials-item">
      <a href="#" class="socials-link-twitter">
        <span class="socials-link-text">twitter</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="socials-item">
      <a href="#" class="socials-link-printerest">
        <span class="socials-link-text">printerest</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="socials-item">
      <a href="#" class="socials-link-facebook">
        <span class="socials-link-text">facebook</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="socials-item">
      <a href="#" class="socials-link-instagram">
        <span class="socials-link-text">instagram</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="socials-item">
      <a href="#" class="socials-link-tumblr">
        <span class="socials-link-text">tumblr</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

Пробовал сделать элемент "а" `display: block;`.
P.S не судите строго, только учусь :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Для ваших классов `socials-link-twitter`, `socials-link-printerest`, `socials-link-instagram`, `socials-link-tumblr`, `socials-link-facebook` необходимо добавить размерности, например

```css
.socials-link-twitter, .socials-link-printerest, .socials-link-instagram, .socials-link-tumblr, .socials-link-facebook {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

В таком случае ссылки будут иметь "физические" размеры и изображения в них будут видны.

```css
.footer {
  background-color: #f4f7f6;
  margin-left: 240px;
  width: 1170px;
  margin-bottom: 75px;
}

.socials {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 400px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.socials-item {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.socials-item:first-child {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.socials-link-twitter {
  background-image: url("https://html-2-diploma/sources/images/social/004-twitter.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.socials-link-printerest {
  background-image: url("https://html-2-diploma/sources/images/social/001-pinterest.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.socials-link-instagram {
  background-image: url("https://html-2-diploma/sources/images/social/005-instagram.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.socials-link-tumblr {
  background-image: url("https://html-2-diploma/sources/images/social/003-tumblr.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.socials-link-facebook {
  background-image: url("https://sources/images/social/002-facebook-logo.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 20px;
}

.socials-link-text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
}

.socials-link-twitter, .socials-link-printerest, .socials-link-instagram, .socials-link-tumblr, .socials-link-facebook {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
  <ul class="socials">
    <li class="socials-item">
      <a href="#" class="socials-link-twitter">
        <span class="socials-link-text">twitter</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="socials-item">
      <a href="#" class="socials-link-printerest">
        <span class="socials-link-text">printerest</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="socials-item">
      <a href="#" class="socials-link-facebook">
        <span class="socials-link-text">facebook</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="socials-item">
      <a href="#" class="socials-link-instagram">
        <span class="socials-link-text">instagram</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="socials-item">
      <a href="#" class="socials-link-tumblr">
        <span class="socials-link-text">tumblr</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```